# Puzzle about virtual function inheritance in C++

Tags: c++

I'm noob in C++, and I have the following header file (Header.h)

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Predicate
{
public:
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

class UnaryIntegerPredicate : public Predicate 
{
public:
    virtual void print();
};

class BiaryIntegerPredicate : public Predicate
{
public:
    virtual void print();
};

#endif
```

and in another separate .cpp file (Source.cpp), I tried to implement the print method, but got an "expected an expression" error.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Header.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

UnaryIntegerPredicate::UnaryIntegerPredicate() : Predicate()
{
    virtual void print()
    {
        cout << "int : boolean" << endl;
    }
}
```

what is wrong here, thanks!

Comment: There's no virtual inheritance here. You have a virtual method but that's it. Also, you don't need a default-constructor because the default one that the compiler provides will call the base class default-constructor (by default ;)). And lastly, if you delete a derived object through a base class pointer your base class will need a virtual destructor in order to avoid undefined behavior. Add `virtual ~Predicate() = default` to your base class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you are probably coming from a Java background. What you need is

```
void UnaryIntegerPredicate::print()
{
    cout << "int : boolean" << endl;
}
```

You don't need the stuff surrounding that. Since you have already declared in your header that `UnaryIntegerPredicate` derives from `Predicate`, you don't mention that again in the implementation file. You show that the print method that you are writing is the print method of the `UnaryIntegerPredicate` class by prefixing the name of the method with the name of the class as I have shown above.

You also don't need the `virtual` keyword in the cpp file because that is already specified in the header file.